# excel: Modify the values of "worksheet1" using values from "worksheet2" where name is the same

Tags: excel, vba

We have two worksheets.

1. Source worksheet is "profes"
2. Target worksheet is "primaria"

The data common to both worksheets is the name column.
ie: David Smith Weston appears in both worksheets.
We need to "lookup" each students name and paste values from "profes" to "primaria". I have most of the code working already BUT I don't know how to add the "lookup" part. As you can see it's wrong.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("profes")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("primaria")

j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("N5:R1000")   ' Do 100 rows
        **If Source.Cells(j, "C").Value = Target.Cells(j, "A").Value** Then
        Target.Cells(j, "N").Value = Source.Cells(j, "D").Value

            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you are not using a lookup (VLOOKUP)?

Comment: `j = j + 1`. That must be out of your IF sentence.You ALWAYS want to increase the value of J, so it checks all cells. Anyways, consider using PivotTables to resume your data by teacher and pupils/students

Comment: `N5:R1000` is **not** 100 rows. It is 996 rows by 5 columns for a total of  4980 cells.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing 2 ranges between 2 worksheets, you have 1 `For` loop, and replace the second loop with the `Match` function.

Once you loop over your "profes" sheet's range, and per cell you check if that value is found within the second range in "primaria" sheet, I used `LookupRng`, as you can see in the code below - you will need to adjust the range cording to your needs.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
Dim MatchRow As Variant
Dim j As Long
Dim C As Range, LookupRng As Range

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("profes")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("primaria")

' set up the Lookup range in "primaria" sheet , this is just an example, modify according to your needs
Set LookupRng = Target.Range("A2:A100")

For Each C In Source.Range("N5:R1000")   ' Do 100 rows
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(C.Value, LookupRng, 0)) Then ' Match was successfull
        MatchRow = Application.Match(C.Value, LookupRng, 0) ' get the row number from "primaria" sheet  where match was found

        Target.Cells(C.Row, "N").Value = Source.Cells(MatchRow, "D").Value
    End If
Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: This works ALMOST perfectly. I suppose I am doing something wrong. I have large blocks of rows where is doesn't add the value but the names do exist in each worksheet. It's as if it's "jumping" blocks then starting again.

Comment: @user3149225 is it exact match or close match ?

Comment: They match exactly.

Comment: Perhaps if we strip out blank spaces that might work. How would I implement that? I mean I suppose it's TRIM but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: @user3149225 if the spaces are in `Source` you can use `Trim(C.Value)`

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I suppose it's impossible for you to know. So thanks for your help. I'm almost there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the worksheet's MATCH function to locate names from the source column C in the target's column A.

Your supplied code is hard to decipher but perhaps this is closer to what you want to accomplish.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    dim j as long, r as variant
    dim source as worksheet, target as worksheet

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("profes")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("primaria")

    with source
        for j = 5 to .cells(.rows.count, "C").end(xlup).row
            r=application.match(.cells(j, "C").value2, target.columns("A"), 0)
            if not iserror(r) then
                target(r, "D").resize(1, 5) = .cells(j, "N").resize(1, 5).value
            end if
        next j
    end with

End Sub
```